# Select, Color Range: error message

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I have a single layer, full RGB color image than I am trying to locate and isolate areas of interest in the "Blue" color range as shown below. (In this case, a missing persons search from aerial photos, based on the color range of known clothing when last seen)

I am trying to utilize the "Select color range" menu item, but I am getting a fairly common message about

> no pixels more than 50% selected.....

However, as shown below, when I do the color range selection to blue, the preview window clearly shows that PS sees the blue range. Yet, I am unable to make it a selection. While I understand i may not see the marching ants, even if I try the selection, modify-expand 40 px, invert, delete.... just toying with isolating areas, there is never a selection.

Either I simply don't understand the tool and/or I'm approaching this problem from the wrong aspect. I'm looking for help on how to fix this or a different approach to the problem.

[image: raw RGBimage]
[image: Zoomed into are to show Blue presence]
[image: Selection mask for BLUE color range]
[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to the message... It's a **warning** and *not* an "error". Errors indicate a *problem* or *inability*. Warnings indicate *important procedural information*.

> No pixels more than 50% selected. **The selection edges will not be visible**

The message does **NOT** state no pixels were selected. What it states is you simply **won't see** any selection edges because all selected pixels are below 50% opacity.

Select Color Range [blues], dismiss warning, make mask, adjust levels on mask...

Clearly the blue is left unmasked.

[image]

Viewing the entire image, will clearly show where the blue is *after* the mask levels have been adjusted to remove some of the transparency around the blues.

[image]

Because the initial selection based on the color range is quite low in opacity....

[image]
<sup>Zoomed in</sup>

.. merely hitting delete after the color range selection is made *may* cause you to not *visibly notice* any drastic difference. Nonetheless a selection **was** made.